# Is it a bad practice to do WebRequests from ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, windows-services, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm doing a web application (ASP.NET MVC) running/deployed in Windows Azure.

Is it a bad practice if I do a lot of WebRequests from this application?, that is:

```
ActionResult SomeAction()
{
      WebRequest.Create(some url);

       ....
}
```

SomeAction is called a lot of times. Also SomeAction might create up to 100 WebRequests, or even more.

**Is this a bad practice?**
**Should I be using a Windows Service instead?** that is:

```
ActionResult SomeAction()
{
      //Save the request in a db and let a Windows Service to poll this db
      //and do the WebRequests from outside the MVC application
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a lot of times"? How many concurrent SomeAction you can have? What type of call do they are?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with what you are doing.  However, a queue with a windows service processing the requests will definitely allow you to manage throughput better.  For instance, what happens if `SomeAction` is called more often than what the website is capable of handling?  Are you ok with some of the requests just getting "lost"?  The decision depends on the actual expected load and whether you can scale to handle it.

Comment: I agree with the others. If this is a user-facing application, this this will be an unpleasant page. If this is something internal for temporary use, something like this might be fine. Ultimately, if you want to scale, then you should follow @mellamokb's suggestion and queue up your 100 jobs and return to the user and have some process to monitor the status of the 100 jobs.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bad practice until this is mandatory for you project.

BTW you can wrap the remote call using some best practice like:

1. if the data in the remote url don't change ofter you can cache results avoiding multiple web request
2. use async await methods (if you are using .NET 4.5) to do the web request asyncronous and with a better performance for your application